# What to do when Pokemon Box full?

Tags: pokemon-go

It's my understanding you need to keep catching pokemon to get the stardust. But now I can't do that and get the message "Your pokemon box is full. You can buy more space in the shop". I don't want to pay money. What do you do now, is there a way to release pokemon?

Answer (score 1):

You can "give Pokemons to the professor". Select a Pokemon, hit the menu button on the bottom right corner and press transfer. Transferred Pokemons do not belong to you anymore, and you get a candy corresponding to the Pokemon type.

Comment: Indeed, this is what you *want* to do - keep the best couple/few of each type and transfer the rest to get candies. These candies are what you will use to evolve Pokémon into new more powerful types, gaining XP for yourself along the way. A very rough yardstick for "best" of each type is their CP level (there are more arcane factors, but this works as a starter); transfer off the lowest CP leveled of each type.